# How to upload multiple images and update an entity at the same time. Rails API and JS frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multipartform-data, rails-activestorage, rails-api

I'm trying to make one API call using formData from a React frontend that has multiple images plus strings/booleans etc. to update an entity

I'm using active storage and I am able to attach multiple images to the entity but when I want to update the entity with strings etc. with one API call (ideally). It says this:

> param is missing or the value is empty: property

I know that the reason is that my formData is structured like this:

```
data: {"title": "xxxxxx", "description": "xxxxxx" etc.}, images[]: File, images[]: File etc.
```

And that I am requiring property as a key and not data:

```
def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:title, :description, :max_guests, :price_per_day, :address,:average_rating, :has_beach_nearby, :has_beds, :has_kitchen, :has_swimming_pool, :has_hdtv,:has_bathtub, :images [])
end
```

But when I don't do it this way, images is not recognised as it is not permitted so the API doesn't receive it

I am attaching images like this (and it works):

```
if params[:images].present?
    params[:images].each do |image|
        @property.images.attach(image)
    end
end
```

Is it possible to upload multiple images and the data using one API call? If not, what do I need to do?

Here is the entire Property controller:

```
class Api::V1::PropertiesController < ApiController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:update, :create, :destroy]
            
    def index
       @properties = Property.all
       render json: @properties
    end
            
    def show
       @property = Property.find(params[:id])
       render json: @property
    end
            
    def update
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
            
      if current_user === @property.user
        if params[:images].present?
           params[:images].each do |image|
              @property.images.attach(image)
           end
        end
            
        @property.update(property_params)
                    
        render json: {
           success: "Successfully updated",property: @property},
           status: 200
      else
        render json: {
           error: "You are not authorized to update this property"}, 
           status: 403
      end
    end
                
    private
    def property_params
       params.require(:property).permit(:title, :description, :max_guests, :price_per_day, :address,:average_rating, :has_beach_nearby, :has_beds, :has_kitchen, :has_swimming_pool, :has_hdtv,:has_bathtub, :images [])
    end
```

Been stuck for a while so would greatly appreciate any help (new to Rails)

Comment: There are some other major issues with this controller thats not really tied to the params. 1) You're doing authorization inline. This leads to code duplication and errors. Use a callback method. 2) You're missing a create method. 3) You're not checking if  `@property.update(property_params)` actually updated the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved it by doing this:

```
    def update
        @property = Property.find(params[:id])
        if current_user === @property.user   
            if params[:images]
                @property.images.attach(params[:images])
            end

            property = @property.update(property_params)

            if property 
                render json: {
                    success: "Successfully updated",
                    property: @property,
                    images: @property.images
                }, status: 200
            else
                render json: {
                    error: "Error when updating this property",
                }, status: 500
            end
        else
            render json: {
                error: "You are not authorized to update this property"
            }, status: 403
        end
    end

    private

    def property_params
        json = JSON.parse(params[:data])
        json = ActionController::Parameters.new(json)
        json.permit(
                :title, :description, :max_guests, 
                :price_per_day, :address, :average_rating, 
                :has_beach_nearby, :has_beds, :has_kitchen, 
                :has_swimming_pool, :has_hdtv, :has_bathtub, images: []
            )
    end
```

Not sure if this is correct but it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Rack uses brackets to pass hashes in formdata:

```
irb(main):005:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("property[title]=foo&property[description]=bar")
=> {"property"=>{"title"=>"foo", "description"=>"bar"}}
```

Arrays can be passed by using empty brackets:

```
irb(main):008:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("property[foo][]=a&property[foo]&[]=property[foo][]=c")
=> {"property"=>{"foo"=>nil}}
```

For multipart form data you would usually use a form (either a visible form or a virtual form) and set the name attribute on the inputs:

```
<form action="/properties" method="post" multipart>
  <input name="property[images][]" type="file" />
  <input name="property[images][]" type="file" />
</form>
```

Rack will stitch the parts of the request body together and create a single parameters hash.

You have a syntax error as well:

```
# Use sensible line lengths and this won't happen as often...
params.require(:property)
      .permit(
         :title, :description, :max_guests, 
         :price_per_day, :address, :average_rating, 
         :has_beach_nearby, :has_beds, :has_kitchen, 
         :has_swimming_pool, :has_hdtv, :has_bathtub, 
         images: []
      )
```

To whitelist arrays or nested parameters you need to use a hash as the last argument to permit. `images: []` will permit an array of permitted scalar which includes `ActionDispatch::UploadedFile`.

If you want to whitelist non-conventional params which contains both nested and flat params you need to get a bit more creative. The key thing to remember is that `ActionController::Parameters` is a hash like object and you can manipulate it like a hash:

```
def property_params   
  params.require(:data)
        .permit(
           :title, :description, :max_guests, 
           :price_per_day, :address, :average_rating, 
           :has_beach_nearby, :has_beds, :has_kitchen, 
           :has_swimming_pool, :has_hdtv, :has_bathtub
        ).merge(
           # fetch is like require but does not raise if the key is not present
           images: params.fetch(:images, []) 
        )
end
```

With ActiveStorage you don't actually [need to manually attach the files](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This makes more sense now. Will update my code and test it

Comment: Hey @max it's still not working. When I look in the console I see this: Parameters: {"property"=>"{\"title\": \"test title\",\n    \"description\": \"blah blah blah.\",\n    \"max_guests\": 3,\n    \"price_per_day\": 2500,\n    \"longitude\": null,\n    \"latitude\": null,\n    \"average_rating\": null,\n    \"has_beach_nearby\": false,\n    \"has_beds\": true,\n    \"has_kitchen\": true,\n    \"has_swimming_pool\": true,\n    \"has_hdtv\": false,\n    \"has_bathtub\": false,\n    \"address\": \"47 Main Road, London\"\n}" - how do I parse the "property" key and permit those nested keys?